# Reduce the following space

Tags: spacing

```
\documentclass{article}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
  \newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}
The following diagram....
    \[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
A \arrow[d,"W_A" swap] \arrow[r,"S"]& A \arrow[d,"T_A"] \\
B \arrow[r,"g" swap] & B\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{proposition}
Now, we state
\end{document}
```

I want to reduce the following space

[image: space]

Comment: There is no predefined `Huge`; `huge` corresponds to `sep=3.6em`. If you want a shorthand for `Huge`, add `\tikzcdset{row sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em,column sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em}` to your document preamble.

Comment: @egreg Thank you but I add it before `\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]` and there is no change in the size.

Comment: `sep=huge` is about the distances between rows and columns, not about the size of the symbols.

Comment: @egreg Thank you but please where exactely should I add `\tikzcdset{row sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em,column sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em}` ? Thanks

Comment: To your document preamble, that is, before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. However I don't see any change when I add `\tikzcdset{row sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em,column sep/Huge/.initial=+4.5em}`.

Comment: I see it if I do `\begin{tikzcd}{sep=huge}` and `\begin{tikzcd}{sep=Huge}`

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forcing a blank line with the `\\` after `B` simply delete the `\\`

Comment: Thank you. Please is it possible to increase the size of the diagram? If I replace `\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]` by `\begin{tikzcd}[sep=Huge]` it does not compilate.

Comment: @Schüler I don't know tikzcd that well but putting `\huge` before the `\[ works

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `sep=huge` is not a font size selection.

Comment: @egreg so I guessed but Op asked for it bigger and said the sep= thing didn't work, so I ignored that...